# Actionscript, best practice for opening multiple files

Tags: actionscript

I need to open 3 files which may or may not exist. I am using FileStream with an event listener on completion of the load.

The code currently works like this

function 1 - Check/load file 1.

On answer - go to function 2.

function 2 - check/load file 2.

On answer - go to function 3.

function 3 - check/load file 3.

On answer - send completion event.

So I have 3 functions to load 3 files.

Does a better way exist. I wish to avoid a third party library.

Comment: Consider accepting answers that are helpful. 

To accept an answer click on the hollow checkmark next to the answer that is best, doing so will increase your reputation and allow more capabilities, See [reputation faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation)  See [this page](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for more detail.

Also please consider going back and accepting past answers, doing so will increase your reputation and allow more capabilities, See [reputation faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation)

Answer (score 0):

A better way would be to use just one function to load all files ? Something like

```
private var _filesArray:Array = ["file1.ext", "file2.ext", "file3.ext"];
private var _loadIndex:int = 0;

private function loadNextFile():void
{
    var _fileToLoad:String = _filesArray[_loadIndex];

    // load your file here
}

private function onFileLoaded():void
{
    checkIfWeAreDone();
}

private function onFileLoadError():void
{
    checkIfWeAreDone();
}

private function checkIfWeAreDone():void
{
    _loadIndex++;

    if (_loadIndex == _filesArray.length)
    {
        // we are done, do something
    }
    else
    {
        loadNextFile();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, thats what I was looking for.